# Typescript Object is possibly null though it has initial value

Tags: typescript, object, null, tslint

```
1: let a: Record<string, any> | null = {};
2: a['b'] = 2;
```

On Row 2, I am getting `TS2531: Object is possibly 'null'` error, though it has initial value.

So, I had to change above code like following

```
1: let a: Record<string, any> | null = {};
2: if (a) {
3:   a['b'] = 2;
4: }
```

Actually, `if` condition is unnecessary, because `a` has value `{}`.
It is just needed for tslint. I want to remove unnecessary `if` condition.
How can I do it?

Comment: Make it `const`.

Comment: No, I give value to `a` later code.

Comment: Yeah, and that's the problem. Cannot expect the TypeScript compiler to keep track of your runtime logic.

Comment: Is there a reason why you aren't doing `a = { b: 2 }`?

Comment: Sorry, but it is just example code, real code is little complex. I can't do it

Comment: An if statement seems like the best way... especially if you need to add more properties.

Comment: It can not reproduce in ts playground, everything work fine

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Non-null assertion` like:

```
a!['b'] = 2;
```

Comment: I am getting new lint error. `Forbidden non-null assertion`